# Disable multitouch on some parts of a touchpad

Tags: x11, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch

The 4th gen Thinkpad Carbon X1 has no mouse buttons below the touchpad, but it is click-sensitive (a so-called *clickpad*). Clicking it on a small band at the bottom provides either a left- or a right-click depending on which side is clicked. (this click is a real mechanic clicking action, not a tap).

My problem is that I am used to previous Thinkpad models, where there were physical mouse keys below the touchpad, so while mousing, I usually rest my thumb on the left key while using my index finger for navigating; then I can click without moving my thumb.

However, on the new touchpad, as soon as my thumb rests on the touchpad, it counts as a touch on its own, and so the thumb and the index finger together become a multi-touch event, stopping the cursor from moving.

How do I disable the multitouch detection for e.g. the lowest 1cm band of the touchpad, so that I can keep my thumb on it and not have it mistaken for a multi-touch gesture? Is there a way to track the other finger and discard the thumb until the physical click?

Comment: I'm on track to solve this using the [`mtrack` driver](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack/blob/master/README.md), but now I've lost the right button  on right-side click...

Comment: The `mtrack`-based solution instead yielded its own [follow-up question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326554/6706)... :(